# Why can't I delete from db using node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, parameterized-query, node-postgres

Is there something special i need to do with a parameterized query?

the following seems to succeed (i'm using a promise-ified `client.query` see end),

```
console.log('cancel for', data);
var cancelInviteQuery = 'delete from friendship where user_1=$1 and user_2_canonical=$2';
return query(cancelInviteQuery, [data.id, data.friend])
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log('ran delete frienship', results);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('failed to drop friendship', error);
  });
```

because i get the output:

```
cancel for {"id":3,"friend":"m"}
ran delete frienship []
```

but then the following query of the database shows the record still exists

```
select * from friendship;
 id | user_1 | user_2 | user_2_canonical | confirmed | ignored 
----+--------+--------+------------------+-----------+---------
  8 |      3 |      9 | m                | f         | f
```

and then the following query succeeds when I make it directly against the database (using psql client)

```
delete from friendship where user_1=3 and user_2_canonical='m'
```

my `query` function (a wrapper for node-postgres's `client.query`):

```
function query(sql, params) {
  var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    pg.connect(CONNECTIONSTRING, function (error, client, done) {
      if (error) { reject(error); return; }

      client.query(sql, params, function (error, result) {
        done(); // Greedy close.
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        else if (result.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
          resolve(result.rows);
        } else { resolve(result.rows); }
      });
    });
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your `data` variable. In the `console.log` it is displaying `"friend":"m"` but you are expecting it to be `"friend":"mike"`.

Comment: sorry @victorkohl it was a sloppy paste.

Comment: Do you solve this problem? If not send more info

Comment: I have not solved it yet, but i still don't know what more to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var cancelInviteQuery = 'delete from friendship where user_1 IN ($1) and user_2_canonical IN ($2)';
```